# Is it possible to pass environment variables to multibranch pipeline job in a time of generating it via DSL?

Tags: jenkins, job-dsl

I want to pass some environment variables in the time of generating the multibranch pipelines, so upon the build start, it will already have these variables.

The only thing I found was this envInject plugin which is not supported by multibranch DSL generation.

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#plugin/envinject

Does anyone know the way to do that?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jenkins DSL and pass the environment variable as mentioned in below links:

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables

Comment: You don't get a question. I need variables passed in a time of generating the job via Job DSL, so when I start that job it will be already there.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you with your problem.
In the normal pipeline or any Jenkins job, we can define parameters which can be accessed via say `${env.SOME_VARIABLE}`

My solution for using environment variables in the Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline.
Scenario. Say you have a variable named VARIABLE whose value is `123456789`.

**Create a secret text with id and description.**

- Secret Text: 123456789

**NOTE**: In Jenkins, the secret text will be completely hidden.

- Id: VARIABLE

**NOTE**: You can define it as you want. If left empty a random value will be assigned to it in the form as45f2sf-43rs-4sdf-s3f3-329f9bc9ae269

- Description: VARIABLE

**NOTE**: Description for the variable.

Once this is created in your multibranch pipeline Jenkinsfile, you can add the following to access those variables whenever required.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
    environment { 
      SECRET_VARIABLE = credentials("VARIABLE") 
    }
    stages {
      stage('stage') {
        steps {
          echo "This is a secret variable: $SECRET_VARIABLE"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

**PS: The variables will appear in a format `****` **

Comment: You don't get a question. I need variables passed in a time of generating the job via Job DSL, so when I start that job it will be already there.